# How can I earn BTCs inside my BITCOIN CORE WALLET desktop app?

Tags: wallet, mining-pools, stratum

**HI. Yes this is my question, Bitcoin Core is not a Mining software?! So, how can I create profit at my wallet? I have CPUMiner in my windows 7 32Bits, there exist a stratum pool adress to mine btcs to my wallet? Please help me and Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin core is a mining software.
You can use rpc `setgenerate` to turn on the mining process.
However, it is nearly impossible for a normal CPU to mine a block(to get rewards) now.
At present, you can't earn anything with a normal CPU now even you join a mining pool. (Thanks to @Murch 's correction)

Comment: He shouldn't join a mining pool its even then impossible to get profits.

Comment: I don't get it. Why not ? He can earn very little bitcoin at least, although the reward is less than the cost.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that he can earn anything at all with CPU mining Bitcoin. Are you actually mining Bitcoin with a home computer and even getting any payouts at all?

Comment: @KevinChia the pools probally wont even recognise his haspower so low is it

Comment: @Fyah Okay, I get it.

Comment: @Murch Sorry, I'm not. So recently you cannot earn anything with a desktop even you join a mining pool?

Comment: You haven't been able to for several years.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to correct it?